# Convert Spark DataFrame to Array / Map / List

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a JSON as below

```
            {"uniqueTranId":"12345", "age":25, "name":"Maichael"}, 
            {"uniqueTranId":"67891", "age":30,"name":"Andy"},
            {"uniqueTranId":"54326", "age":19, "name":"Justin" }
```

From the Json I have a DataFrame as

```
                    +----+--------+------------+
                    | age|    name|uniqueTranId|
                    +----+--------+------------+
                    |  25|Maichael|       12345|
                    |  30|    Andy|       67891|
                    |  19|  Justin|       54326|
                    +----+--------+------------+
```

I would like to convert this DataFrame as below.

```
   List(
       ("12345"), Map["SomeConstant", Array[(uniqueTranId -> 12345, age -> 25, name -> Maichael)]] ,
       ("67891"), Map["SomeConstant", Array[(uniqueTranId -> 67891, age -> 30, name -> Andy)]],
       ("54326"), Map["SomeConstant", Array[(uniqueTranId -> 67891, age -> 19, name -> Justin)]] 
       )
```

The following is the Type I am looking for.

```
List([uniqueTranId,  Map["SomeConstant", Array[(json_key -> json_value)]])])
```

Any immediate help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You do not need spark if your expected end-result is a scala list you collected from the DF..  Just perform the mapping using collected Rows

Comment: @Micheal Lemay...I tried...**val tempArray = df.collect.map(r => Map(df.columns.zip(r.toSeq):_*))** Map(age -> 25, name -> Maichael, uniqueTranId -> 12345)
Map(age -> 30, name -> Andy, uniqueTranId -> 67891)
Map(age -> 19, name -> Justin, uniqueTranId -> 54326)  and **val temp = List(tempArray.map(p => (p.getOrElse("uniqueTranId", null), p)):_*)** (12345,Map(age -> 25, name -> Maichael, uniqueTranId -> 12345))
(67891,Map(age -> 30, name -> Andy, uniqueTranId -> 67891))
(54326,Map(age -> 19, name -> Justin, uniqueTranId -> 54326))...after that no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it..

```
val data = sc.parallelize(List(
  """{"uniqueTranId":"12345", "age":25, "name":"Maichael"}""", 
  """{"uniqueTranId":"67891", "age":30,"name":"Andy"}""",
  """{"uniqueTranId":"54326", "age":19, "name":"Justin" }"""))

val df = spark.read.json(data)
val collected = df.collect

collected.map(row => {
  (row.getString(row.fieldIndex("uniqueTranId")),
   Map("someconstant" -> row.getValuesMap(df.columns).map(x => (x._1, x._2.toString)).toArray))
})
```